# What is "RTL mode" (IE)?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've seen many places referencing "RTL mode" for Internet Explorer, but didn't know what it was.

After many Google searches, I was not able to determine what "RTL" stood for, therefore I thought it good to ask here.

Comment: RTL - Right-to-Left, used for text in languages such as Arabic and Hebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*RTL* means [Right-to-left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) and in the web context it generally refers to support of languages that are written from right to left. In HTML, this is usually done using the `dir` attribute, setting it to a value of `rtl`.

You can see an example using English [here](http://jsbin.com/oHukEFE/1/). Of course this does not make much sense with English, but I can’t write any RTL language… ^^

Answer (score 1):

It appears to stand for ["Right-to-left"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left), as in, the mode where a user interface displays text in a right-to-left orientation, for use with languages written this way, such as Hebrew and Arabic.

Finally found the answer on [this page](http://www.drexplain.com/software-documentation-tool/rtl-text-typing-mode-support.php).

Answer (score 0):

"Right To Left" perhaps? Are there any other options available?

Answer (score 0):

RTL stands for Right to Left

English is written Left side of Page to the right side of the page.

Some languages are written RTL  from the right hand side of the page to the left.